# How to output array of predicted results saved in picklemodel to flask app?

Tags: flask, model, pickle, random-forest

I have a model created in pickle and it has predicted results in the form of array. My question is how do I output the arrays on my flask app?

I created a flask app that calls the model.pkl but I'm running to some errors when I run flask. It says, feature names unseen at fit time.

Does it mean the model.pkl is the error or the error is my flask app?

Answer (score 0):

The message you're facing, which states "feature names not observed during training," indicates a possible inconsistency between the features used for predictions in your Flask application and those available when the model in the model.pkl file was trained. This situation is more likely a result of how you're handling input data within your Flask application, as opposed to an issue inherent to the model.pkl file.